# Nested <li> inside <li> filled background

Tags: html, css

There is a sidebar menu containing `<ul>` with `<li>`, inside some of the `<li>` is another `<ul>` with `<li>`. When I hover over to `<li>` it shows another `<ul>`. What I am facing now is that when I hover on the `<li>` and `<ul>` shows in it. It is all filled with background color. But, I need to show it over only the first `<li>` not others. Example included in images below.

First image is my attempt. Second image is what I am looking for.

[image]

Here is the code for it

```css
    /* Menu CSS */#cssmenu,
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: url(images/highlight-bg.png) repeat;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
#cssmenu:before,
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:before,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  zoom: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
#cssmenu > ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 18px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  background: #d6d6d6; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d6d6d6 0%, #e56e1d 49%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d6d6d6 0%,#e56e1d 49%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d6d6d6 0%,#e56e1d 49%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d6d6d6', endColorstr='#e56e1d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
  line-height: 18px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-right: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5) solid 1px;
  padding-right: 38px;
  padding-left: 38px;
}
/*
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
*/
/* Childs */
#cssmenu > ul ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
#cssmenu > ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu > ul ul li a {
  padding: 6px 26px;
  background-color: #e56e1d;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 194px;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #ee974f;
}
```

```html
<ul id="sidebar">
    <li><a href='#'><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit </span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Amet, consectetur </span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Adipisici elit, sed </span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Eiusmod </span></a>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Tempor incidunt </span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Excepteur</span></a></li> 
            <li><a href='#'><span>Sint obcaecat</span></a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Obcaecat</span></a></li> 
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Cupiditat</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Cupiditat non </span></a></li>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Proident.</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Ut labore et </span></a>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Dolore magna aliqua</span></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add your code here as well so that we can help you.

Comment: you need something like the first-cild selector.
But without your Code i cannot 
say it excactly

Comment: What if you do `li:hover > ul { background-color: transparent; }`

Comment: last answer do not work

Comment: Please include your CSS as well. (I've cast a pre-emptive reopen vote since you've shown willingness to improve the question [thanks for that!])

Answer (score 0):

You should change the background of just the link you want to target, instead of the li tag that also contains the sub-menu...

```
.sidebar > li > a {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

---

Just noticed in the CSS that you are targeting the link, but the link color starts off as the hover color...  here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kbmr4wy9/2/

You'll want to edit the background in the selector:

```
#cssmenu > ul ul li a {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *Tempor incidunt* list item includes the nested `ul` within it. That means that when you apply a background to the `li`, you are also providing a background to the nested list.

In order to alter this to your expected result, here are two reasonable solutions:

1. Assuming that `<a href='#'><span>Tempor incidunt </span></a>` has a width that spans the whole navigation, apply the background to this anchor element instead of the `li`. This works because the anchor tag does not wrap the nested `ul`.
2. Give the nested `ul` a grey background. This will overlay the blue gradient, and make it appear as expected for your design.

Both these solutions work. If I were you, I would lean towards (1), since it is slightly cleaner. However, it does require your anchor tag to be full width. However, this may be better for usability, since the click target would be the same width as the navigation.